# Post Upgrade Content Editor Font Problem

Tags: content-editor, upgrade

Post upgrading with the Express Migration Tool, my fonts and forms are a little wonky. If I didnt know any better Id say a css file was missing. But, nothing in the browser console to this point.

Example - This is how 8.2 Upgrade 3 should look:

[image]

And my upgraded instance

[image]

Its particularly noticeable on dialogs. Everything is small and scrunched together:

[image]

Comment: Did you clear all your browser caches?

Comment: I am an idiot. Can you add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the steps to complete upgrades is always to clear the caches on the browsers that are used for Sitecore administration. Static files used in there get stuck in those caches causing issues (mostly css like issues as the one you are facing, sometimes js issues).

Clearing the cache should do the trick - and don't forget to inform other editors to do the same.